# jQuery: .after() is causing multiplication element duplication glitch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, I am getting an href value, then taking that value, creating a new element after the one im getting it from, then applying the href to the new one. The problem is, after every time I copy and paste this code, one for facebook, and one for twitter, as a share button, it multiplies from 2 to 3, showing 1 twitter button, and two facebook buttons. This has completely stumped me, never ran into this issue before.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mm').each(function () {
        $('a', this).after('<br><a class="tw">twitter</a><br>');
        var lnk = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        $('.tw', this).attr('href', lnk);
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mm').each(function () {
        $('a', this).after('<br><a class="fb">facebook</a><br>');
        var lnk = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        $('.fb', this).attr('href', lnk);
    });
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/zachreynolds/pen/oEBMzz

Comment: zach reynolds  check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are applying `.each()` 2 times.

You need to Merge your code into one `.each()` like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.mm').each(function () {
    var lnk = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(this).find('a').after('<br><a class="tw" href="'+lnk+'">twitter</a><br><br><a class="fb" href="'+lnk+'">Facebook</a><br>');
  });
});
```

***Working example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.mm').each(function () {
    var lnk = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(this).find('a').after('<br><a class="tw" href="'+lnk+'">twitter</a><br><br><a class="fb" href="'+lnk+'">Facebook</a><br>');
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.mm{background:#ccc;margin:5px}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #323232;
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 1em 3em;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
}
 
h1 {line-height: 2;}
p{ font-size: 1.2em;}
pre {
  padding: .5em;
  color:#bada55; /* bright green */
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  font-size:1em;
  background-color: #000;}
  
}
code {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size:.25em;
  font-family:verdana;
}
a:link {color:#DB2929;text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited{color:green;text-decoration:none;}
a:hover{color:green;}
a:active{color:red;}

.tw,.fb{width:100px;height:33px;padding:7px;}
.tw {background:#09f}
.fb {background:#46a}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cc-m-8497708420" class="j-module n j-rss ">
  <div class="rssFeed">
    <h3><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/sustainability/top/.rss?sort=top&amp;t=week&amp;limit=5" target="_blank">sustainability</a></h3>
    <div class="mm">
      <span class="rssFeedTitle j-rss-feed-title">Trees that helped save America's farms during the Dust Bowl are now under threat</span><br><br>
      <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/sustainability/comments/7vqzku/trees_that_helped_save_americas_farms_during_the/" target="_blank">&gt;&gt; Read More</a><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="wrappedtext">(Tue, 06 Feb 2018)</div>
    
    <div class="mm">
      <span class="rssFeedTitle j-rss-feed-title">Can Money Grow on Trees? Across the world, businesses are making money by restoring forests and farmland.</span><br><br>
      <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/sustainability/comments/7vx4qu/can_money_grow_on_trees_across_the_world/" target="_blank">&gt;&gt; Read More</a><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="wrappedtext">(Wed, 07 Feb 2018)    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```